# Semidefinite programming over infinite dimensional space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

During my calculations I've encountered a semidefinite program, e.g.

$$\max\{ \lVert X \rVert : \lVert X \circ M \rVert \le 1 \}$$

where $\circ$ denotes the entry-wise multiplication (this is called filtered $\gamma_2$ norm). In my case, the rows and columns of $X$ are indexed by the elements of a set $S$, which is a finite subset of the complex circle. Now I'm interested to extend the case to continuously infinite $S$ (always within the unit circle).

My question is: does the theory of semidefinite programming (or more generally, convex optimization) still hold over continuously infinite Hilbert spaces, or there are some results that hold only in the finite case? Any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: In my opinion, this question is way to broad. There are many results from convex optimization which carry over to Hilbert spaces, but sometimes you have to fight with weak convergence.

Comment: @gerw My biggest concern is about duality theory, if weak duality still holds and Slater's condition is still sufficient for strong duality under the assumption that the solution space contains bounded linear operator over even continuously infinite Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote about duality, you might be interested in the concept of [Fenchel duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%27s_duality_theorem). This holds even in Banach spaces (and there are also variants in topological vector spaces).